# Creating fd in a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, file-descriptor

In my kernel module I'd like to create multiple FDs, and pass them later to the user-space via `ioctl`.

The user-space code will use these FDs to wait for an event using `poll()` or `select()`.

If I were creating such FDs in the user-space, I'd call `eventfd()`, but how do that in the kernel-space?

Answer (score 0):

According to system call's expansion macro (`#define SYSCALL_DEFINEx`) in `syscalls.h`, maybe you can call `sys_eventfd` or `sys_eventfd2` in the kernel-space.

Comment: It seems that neither of these functions is exported from the kernel. When building, I get `WARNING: "sys_eventfd" [/my_path/my_module.ko] undefined!`

Comment: From what I can gather, doing syscalls from kernelspace is deprecated.  I'm not sure what is supposed to replace it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841327/can-we-call-system-call-in-kernel-space)