# How to call system call in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to trigger system call in kernel space and it works fine if the system call does not take arguments such as `getpid()`.

The method how I do it:

1. get the address of system table

```c
static void **syscall_table;
```

2. use it with system call number you want and as a function pointer:

```c
typedef long (*sys_call_ptr_t)(const struct __user pt_regs *);

// call system call
((sys_call_ptr_t *)syscall_table)[system_call_number](reg);
```

3. if system call have argument, store them into regs before calling it:

```c
struct __user pt_regs *reg = kmalloc....;
reg->di = ...
reg->si = ...
```

Currently, I'm trying to use `write` but it fails.

```c
write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

For `buf`, I've tried both user space address and kernel space address. `count` may not be a problem. So, I guess problem maybe occur in file descriptor (maybe `fd` is different between in lower level's and user space's). For basic testing, I only want to write text into terminal, so `fd` should be `1` (at least in user space).

There're two questions here:

1. In some reason, I need to stick to the method calling syscall described above. Is it reasonable or any step I miss and cause failure of using `write`?
2. If something wrong when I called `write`? Does the problem come from `fd`? If so, how do I get the corresponding `fd` with `1` in user space?

Comment: Using system calls from the kernel is rarely a good idea. Instead, use in-kernel functions suited for your needs. About writing files in the kernel space, see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module.

Comment: I did the same question some time ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161530/perform-a-syscall-in-a-kernel-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Foreword

By definition, a system call is a service offered by the system to the user space applications. When one is running inside the system, he should not call
a service destined to user space. Hence, this is unadvised to make it.

### First try with a kernel space buffer

The *write()* system call is defined in *fs/read_write.c*. It calls *ksys_write()* which calls *vfs_write()*:

```c
ssize_t vfs_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    ssize_t ret;

    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))
        return -EBADF;
    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_CAN_WRITE))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (unlikely(!access_ok(buf, count)))
        return -EFAULT;

    ret = rw_verify_area(WRITE, file, pos, count);
    if (!ret) {
        if (count > MAX_RW_COUNT)
            count =  MAX_RW_COUNT;
        file_start_write(file);
        ret = __vfs_write(file, buf, count, pos);
        if (ret > 0) {
            fsnotify_modify(file);
            add_wchar(current, ret);
        }
        inc_syscw(current);
        file_end_write(file);
    }

    return ret;
}
[...]
ssize_t ksys_write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    struct fd f = fdget_pos(fd);
    ssize_t ret = -EBADF;

    if (f.file) {
        loff_t pos, *ppos = file_ppos(f.file);
        if (ppos) {
            pos = *ppos;
            ppos = &pos;
        }
        ret = vfs_write(f.file, buf, count, ppos);
        if (ret >= 0 && ppos)
            f.file->f_pos = pos;
        fdput_pos(f);
    }

    return ret;
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE3(write, unsigned int, fd, const char __user *, buf,
        size_t, count)
{
    return ksys_write(fd, buf, count);
}
```

The file descriptor passed as first parameter is not a problem. The value passed from user space is used to retrieve the *file* structure of the output file (in *ksys_write()*). But the second parameter must reference a user space memory area.
In *vfs_write()*, a check is done on the second parameter:

```c
    if (unlikely(!access_ok(buf, count)))
        return -EFAULT;
```

*access_ok()* checks if the buffer is in the user-level space. Hence, if you
pass an address referencing the kernel space, the returned code from *read()* will be **-EFAULT** (-14).

The example below is a simple module calling the *write()* system call with a kernel space buffer. On x86_64, the convention for the parameters of the system calls are:

```
   RDI = arg#0
   RSI = arg#1
   RDX = arg#2
   R10 = arg#3
   R8  = arg#4
   R9  = arg#5
```

```c
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

typedef int (* syscall_wrapper)(struct pt_regs *);

unsigned long sys_call_table_addr;

#define DEV_NAME "[DEVICE2]"


#define DEV_STR  DEV_NAME "String from driver"

static char buf[1024];


static int __init device2_init(void) {

  syscall_wrapper write_syscall;
  int rc;
  struct pt_regs param;

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "module has been loaded\n");

  sys_call_table_addr = kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "sys_call_table@%lx\n", sys_call_table_addr);

  write_syscall = ((syscall_wrapper *)sys_call_table_addr)[__NR_write];

  /*
    Call to write() system call with a kernel space buffer
  */
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s\n", DEV_STR);
  param.di = 1;
  param.si = (unsigned long)buf;
  param.dx = strlen(buf);
  rc = (* write_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "write() with a kernel space buffer = %d\n", rc);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit device2_exit(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "module has been unloaded\n");
}

module_init(device2_init);
module_exit(device2_exit);
```

At module insertion time, we can verify that the system call returns -EFAULT:

```
$ sudo insmod ./device2.ko
$ dmesg
[15716.262977] [DEVICE2]module has been loaded
[15716.270566] [DEVICE2]sys_call_table@ffffffff926013a0
[15716.270568] [DEVICE2]write() with a kernel space buffer = -14
```

But the same module with a system call like *dup()* which involves a file descriptor but no user space buffers, this works. Let's change the previous code with:

```c
static int __init device2_init(void) {

  syscall_wrapper write_syscall;
  syscall_wrapper dup_syscall;
  syscall_wrapper close_syscall;
  int rc;
  struct pt_regs param;

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "module has been loaded\n");

  sys_call_table_addr = kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "sys_call_table@%lx\n", sys_call_table_addr);

  write_syscall = ((syscall_wrapper *)sys_call_table_addr)[__NR_write];
  dup_syscall = ((syscall_wrapper *)sys_call_table_addr)[__NR_dup];
  close_syscall = ((syscall_wrapper *)sys_call_table_addr)[__NR_close];

  /*
    Call to write() system call with a kernel space buffer
  */
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s\n", DEV_STR);
  param.di = 1;
  param.si = (unsigned long)buf;
  param.dx = strlen(buf);
  rc = (* write_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "write() with a kernel space buffer = %d\n", rc);

  /*
    Call to dup() system call
  */
  param.di = 1;
  rc = (* dup_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "dup() = %d\n", rc);

  /*
    Call to close() system call
  */
  param.di = 0;
  rc = (* close_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "close() = %d\n", rc);

  /*
    Call to dup() system call ==> Must return 0 as it is available
  */
  param.di = 1;
  rc = (* dup_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "dup() = %d\n", rc);

  return 0;
}
```

The result of *dup()* is OK:

```
$ sudo insmod ./device2.ko
$ dmesg
[17444.098469] [DEVICE2]module has been loaded
[17444.106935] [DEVICE2]sys_call_table@ffffffff926013a0
[17444.106937] [DEVICE2]write() with a kernel space buffer = -14
[17444.106939] [DEVICE2]dup() = 4
[17444.106940] [DEVICE2]close() = 0
[17444.106940] [DEVICE2]dup() = 0
```

The first call to *dup()* returns 4 because the current process is `insmod`. The latter opened the module file and got file descriptor 3. Hence, the first available file descriptor is 4. The second call to *dup()* returns 0 because we closed the file descriptor 0.

### Second try with a user space buffer

To use a user space buffer, let's add some file operations to the kernel module (*open()*, *release()* and *write()*). In the *write()* entry point we echo back what is passed from user space into **stderr** (file descriptor 2) using the user space buffer passed to the *write()* entry point:

```c
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

typedef int (* syscall_wrapper)(struct pt_regs *);

static unsigned long sys_call_table_addr;

#define DEV_NAME "[DEVICE2]"

static syscall_wrapper write_syscall;

static ssize_t device2_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
  struct pt_regs param;
  int rc;

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "write %p, %zu\n", buff, len);

  /*
    Call to write() system call to echo the write to stderr
  */
  param.di = 2;
  param.si = (unsigned long)buff;
  param.dx = len;
  rc = (* write_syscall)(&param);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "write() = %d\n", rc);

  return len;  // <-------------- To stop the write
}

static int device2_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "open\n");
    return 0;
}

static int device2_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "released\n");
    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations fops =
{
    .owner= THIS_MODULE,
    .write=device2_write,
    .open= device2_open,
    .release= device2_release

};

struct cdev *device_cdev;
dev_t deviceNumbers;

static int __init device2_init(void) {

  int rc;

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "module has been loaded\n");

  // This returns the major number chosen dynamically in deviceNumbers
  rc = alloc_chrdev_region(&deviceNumbers, 0, 1, DEV_NAME);

  if (rc < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT DEV_NAME "Error registering: %d\n", rc);
    return -1;
  }

  device_cdev = cdev_alloc();

  cdev_init(device_cdev, &fops);

  cdev_add(device_cdev, deviceNumbers, 1);

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "initialized (major number is %d)\n", MAJOR(deviceNumbers));

  sys_call_table_addr = kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "sys_call_table@%lx\n", sys_call_table_addr);

  write_syscall = ((syscall_wrapper *)sys_call_table_addr)[__NR_write];

  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "write_syscall@%p\n", write_syscall);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit device2_exit(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO DEV_NAME "module has been unloaded\n");
}

module_init(device2_init);
module_exit(device2_exit);
```

The loading of the module:

```
$ sudo insmod device2.ko
$ dmesg
[ 2255.183196] [DEVICE2]module has been loaded
[ 2255.183202] [DEVICE2]initialized (major number is 508)
[ 2255.193255] [DEVICE2]sys_call_table@ffffffffbcc013a0
[ 2255.193256] [DEVICE2]write_syscall@0000000030394929
```

Make the device entry in the file system to be able to write into it:

```
$ sudo mknod /dev/device2 c 508 0
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/device2
$ sudo ls -l /dev/device2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 508, 0 janv.  24 16:55 /dev/device2
```

The writing into the device triggers the expected echo on **stderr**:

```
$ echo "qwerty for test purposes" > /dev/device2
qwerty for test purposes
$ echo "another string" > /dev/device2
another string
$ dmesg
[ 2255.183196] [DEVICE2]module has been loaded
[ 2255.183202] [DEVICE2]initialized (major number is 508)
[ 2255.193255] [DEVICE2]sys_call_table@ffffffffbcc013a0
[ 2255.193256] [DEVICE2]write_syscall@0000000030394929
[ 2441.674250] [DEVICE2]open
[ 2441.674268] [DEVICE2]write 0000000032fb5249, 25
[ 2441.674281] [DEVICE2]write() = 25
[ 2441.674286] [DEVICE2]released
[ 2475.538140] [DEVICE2]open
[ 2475.538159] [DEVICE2]write 0000000032fb5249, 15
[ 2475.538171] [DEVICE2]write() = 15
[ 2475.538175] [DEVICE2]released
```

Comment: The value return from `write` is negative(-14), is this under expectation? Also, your `fd` is `1`, did this mean that some string will show up on terminal as output?

Comment: When a system call fails inside the kernel, it returns a negative error code. The GLIBC in user space translates it into a positive number and put it into errno. I updated my answer with dup() syscall.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Why you close fd0 (`param.di = 0`) instead of `fd1`? or just for testing?

Comment: I updated my answer. This is to show that dup() works. This is for test purposes.

Comment: Thanks for update again. The thing you did is similar to what I have done. Have you succeed to write string into any file descriptor? I'm pretty sure the address of `buf` I passed into `write` is in user space (I pinned user page into kernel).

Comment: I updated the answer with a 3rd part to show that the write() works with a user space address.